# Logger (wsdl4j) doesn't work in Centos 7

Tags: java, file, logging, centos

I have a VPS, with Centos 7. And I have a backend in java, with logger WSDLJ4, that instantiate so:

```
    Handler consoleHandler = new ConsoleHandler();
    Handler fileHandler = new FileHandler(ARCHIVO_LOG_C, false);
    SimpleFormatter simpleFormatter = new SimpleFormatter();
    fileHandler.setFormatter(simpleFormatter);
    LOGGER.addHandler(consoleHandler);
    LOGGER.addHandler(fileHandler);
    consoleHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    fileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

When I executed the program in Windows, with a embedded tomcat in spring boot, works perfectly, create a **logger.log** but when I executed in Centos, don't do nothing.

```
public final static String ARCHIVO_LOG = "///opt/tomcat/Firebase/logger.log";
public final static String ARCHIVO_LOG_C = "G:\\logger.log";
```

When I used in Centos, change the variable "FileHandler" for 'ARCHIVO_LPG'

What happen?

Thank for the advantage.

Comment: Why the extra `//` at the beginning? Did you try with just `/opt/tomcat/Firebase/logger.log`? Also, did you check `/opt/tomcat/Firebase/`write permission for the user?

Comment: I have an archive there, for firebase uses. This uses extra //.

Comment: The FileHandler either throws an exception on construction or creates a log in the home folder of the user when things go wrong.  Have you checked if either of those are happening?